# REST related/nested objects URL standard

Tags: rest, api-design

if /wallet returns a list a wallets and each wallet has a list of transactions. What is the standard OpenAPI/REST standard?

For example,

`http://localhost:8000/api/wallets/` gives me

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "user": 1,
            "address": "3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd",
            "balance": "2627199.00000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

`http://localhost:8000/api/wallets/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd/` gives me

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "address": "3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd",
    "balance": "2627199.00000000"
}
```

If I wanted to add a transactions list, what is the standard way to form this?

`http://localhost:8000/api/wallets/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd/transactions` ?

`http://localhost:8000/api/wallets/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd/transactions?offset=100` for pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resources.  What it would instead expect is that you have representations of [links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288) between resources, along with meta data describing the nature of the link.

So this schema is *fine*.

```
/api/wallets/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd
/api/wallets/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd/transactions
```

And this schema is also *fine*.

```
/api/wallets/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd
/api/transactions/3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd
```

---

As far as I can tell, OpenAPI also gives you the freedom to design your resource model the way that works best for you (it just tells you one possible way to *document* the resource model you have selected).

Comment: Your username conflicts with this well-reasoned answer